What is the return current path for inner layer routed trace (six layer PCB)
I have a question about the return current for signal traces that are routed in the inner layer of a six layer PCB.
I am designing, like I said, a six layer board. The stackup is like this:

Layer 1: TOP
Layer 2: GND
Layer 3: Signal
Layer 4: PWR
Layer 5: GND
Layer 6: BOTTOM

Some signal traces are on layer 3, so I added stitching via's for the return current next to the via used to route the trace to a different layer. The signal traces (on layer 3) are USB3 and 4-bit SDIO. I wanted to route all the differential pair traces on the TOP and BOTTOM layer, but because of limited space I have on the PCB I had to route them on layer 3.
But my question is: Is it important to add stitching capacitors at the beginning and end of the trace that is on layer 3?
Because layer 2 and 4 are both reference planes, so wouldn't layer 2 be the path of least resistance?
Thanks,
-Dj

A little off topic - you have an unbalanced stack. Do you intend to put this through reflow?

@PeterSmith Yes, and the fact that you're asking suggests this can cause issues?

USB, which version / maximum speed? SDIO, signal level, edge rate, max clock rate?

If you just pour copper on all the signal layers you should be fine

Also consider that noise can couple between layer 4 and layer 3, if not separated properly.

@TimWilliams It's USB3 and SDIO is 4bit, 3.3V with 25MHz

@Tyassin So instead of using stitching capacitors, I should just pour copper on toplayer, layer 3 and bottomlayer? Do you perhaps have a link or source where I can read about this? I want to fully understand.

Switching between layer 1 and layer six, here stitching vias are necessary as you have already done. Routing on layer 3 could also be OK as long as you keep in mind how the layer 4 (PWR) is routed. If you have these high speed traces close to a low noise analog PSU on layer 4, this could introduce noise into this. Also the spacing between the layers are important, in what can be considered a reference plane. If the distance between layer 2 and 3 is much smaller than between layer 3 and 4, that is best.
If layer 4 is very close to layer 3 then this can be considered to be the main reference plane and then you have to find out how the return current will come back. Because the reference plane is not GND, the return current will have to find a way back through stitching capacitors or decoupling capacitors, as you obviously cannot stich PWR and GND together with vias. Either way the return route need to be considered carefully, but there is a risk it lead to EMI issues.
What is really important to remember is that the return/displacement current for a signal will be present on a plane no matter if we call it GND, PWR or signal. So a rule of thump is to have a GND plane next to every signal or power plane AND it need to be close to be considered the main reference plane.
Look up Rick Hartley videos for more info.
